# Excel how do i check a cell in excel, if it's empty then shift the contents of the previous cell to current cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[I have some data like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEDqC.jpg)

I need to move the thirdname field into lastname if the lastname cell is empty. If there is content already in lastname cell, it should skip that cell and move to the next cell

i tried this "=IF(ISBLANK(lastnamecell),thirdnamecell,lastnamecell)" but it's not correctly copying the contents from thirdname to lastname.

Comment: You can not use a formula that refers to itself.  You will need to place the formula you have in a third column.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set last name =ThirdName. And overwrite it with last name if necessary.

```
+ B         | C 
| ThirdName | LastName
| Abc       | ==IF(ISBLANK(B2), "", B2)
| Def       | No problem
```

Or another option is: create another column to type lastname, apply your formula and hide the real lastname column.

Comment: this is same problem i had when i was trying the previous time too. When i have both lastname and thridname columns empty, it's giving me 0 as a result in the second lastname column cells. is there any way to fix this?

Comment: how do combine this and my other formula? i'm confused.. can you give me the formula that will ignore if both thirdname and lastname are empty but will move thirdname to lastname if there is a thridname but no lastname. thanks